# Is Spring Dependency Injection only for singleton instances?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am currently studying about the spring framework and its dependency injection system.

I have learned about the use of FileSystemXmlApplicationContext and how we define the dependencies in a XML file using the Beans tag.

I understand that the beans are so called Spring Beans which are singleton types by nature. With this in mind that begs the question if the Spring DI system is only for singleton classes?

Comment: No, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various other scopes offered by Spring DI, other than Singleton

Listing various Spring scopes:

- singleton
- prototype
- request
- session
- application
- websocket

***Prototype*** : This scope will give you a **new object** on every DI.

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes